# Error creating bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying with OAuth2,am new to it,please help me out in solving this

```
*org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:556)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 55 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:94)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:292)
        at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:387)
        at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:114)
        at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:72)
        at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:56)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1149)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:416)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:250)
        at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:397)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
        at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:279)
        at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:177)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:236)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1347)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        ... 61 more*
```

**WEB.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <servlet>  
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
 </servlet>  
 <servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
 </servlet-mapping>  
 <listener>  
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
 </listener>  

 <context-param>  
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
  <param-value>    
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml,    
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml  
        </param-value>  
 </context-param>  

 <!-- Spring Security -->  

 <filter>  
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
 </filter>  

 <filter-mapping>  
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
 </filter-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

**Spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:http pattern="/protected/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" method="GET" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="sourceList" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="in.AAAGuestServiceImpl">
        <property name="id" value="webapi" />
        <property name="secretKey" value="mycompanykey" />
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider"
        class="in.AAAUserAuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120"></property>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="MyResource" class="in.UserResource"></bean>
    <bean id="aaaProxy" class="in.AAAProxy"></bean>
</beans>
```

**Used Jars**

- Spring security config 4.0.3
- Spring security web 4.0.3
- Spring
  security core4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, this was because of **jars mismatch** and i missed **`@Service`** annotation for one `bean class`.

### Jars which are used now

1. Spring 4.2.3
2. Spring security 3.2.5(previous 4.0.3)
3. Spring security OAuth2-1.0.5(previous 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` has no property named `sourceList`. Remove it.

```
    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Then you have to clean your project and see.

Comment: cancelling refresh attempt: *org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':
Cannot resolve reference 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0];
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0':
Cannot resolve reference 'clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [3];*

Answer (score -2):

I solved my error by updating mysql-connector-java-bin.jar to  version 5 up.